# Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [ebsMSP]

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have set up Multi-Org(4 org) Fabric. Each org is having one peer (peer0). While doing query on 2nd org I'm getting below error:

```
Calling One getOrdersByEBSDashboardStatus Function..
error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [ebsMSP]
    at new createStatusError (/home/vikas123/fabric-samples/kpn_grpc/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /home/vikas123/fabric-samples/kpn_grpc/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
Query has completed, checking results
error from query =  { Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [ebsMSP]
    at new createStatusError (/home/vikas123/fabric-samples/kpn_grpc/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /home/vikas123/fabric-samples/kpn_grpc/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15
  code: 2,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
  details: 'access denied: channel [mychannel] creator org [ebsMSP]' }
```

At the same time when I checked docker logs respective to this org, I see message **: channel [mychannel]: MSP error: channel doesn't exist.**

Please check attached query file:https://github.com/SakivV/dockergit/blob/master/queryebs.js

Comment: I got the root cause of the issue. Peer not joined channel hence this error was there. We can check whether Peer has joined channel or not with below steps: 1. Get in to peer container with **docker exec -it <containername>** 2. Run **peer channel list** this will display list of channel peer has joined. In my case no channel is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Remember once you have generated the crypto material you have to create the channel automatically and doesn't need to create the channel anymore but you have to join all peers one by one and then update the channel regarding that join.

```
peer channel fetch 0  $CHANNEL_NAME.block -c $CHANNEL_NAME  -o orderer.example.com:7050
peer channel join -b  $CHANNEL_NAME.block -c $CHANNEL_NAME  -o orderer.example.com:7050
```

There are anchor peer  tx into channel-artifacts/ (Org1Panchors.tx)

```
peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/Org1Panchors.tx
```